# Найти позицию дочернего элемента

Tags: jquery

Допустим, есть родительский элемент, а в нём несколько дочерних:

```
...
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
...
```

Допустим, что я делаю выборку всех `span` при помощи jQuery-селектора:

```
$('span')
```

Этот jQuery-селектор вернёт мне массив длинной в 4 элемента. Могу ли я как-то узнать, что, например, 3 элемент идёт именно третьим?

Comment: а второй - вторым? Где он "идет"?

Comment: @Igor что он идёт именно третьим внутри своего родителя.

Comment: Вы просто повторили фразу из вопроса.

Comment: жквери и без того вернет вам элементы в том порядке, в котором они "идут".

Comment: @Инквизитор осталось выяснить смысл слова "идут". Что-то мне подсказывает, что в вопросе имеется в виду относительное положение элементов на странице. Но ТС не хочет пока в этом признаваться.

Comment: Похоже, что вы чего-то недоговариваете. Если ванговать, то может вам нужно сравнить исходную последовательность элементов с  последовательностью после каких-то манипуляций?

Comment: @Igor, я думаю, имеется в виду порядок их размещения в DOM. То бишь, порядок их фактического появления на странице.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr =[];
arr = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
```

Элементы на странице располагаются сверху вниз. Когда обернёшь их в массив, порядок не поменяется, т.е. первый 'span' будет в позиции arr[0]

Comment: Это ответ на какой вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вот так:

```js
var arrList = [];
$('.list span').each(function(){
 var spanIndex = $(this).index();
 arrList.push(spanIndex);
});

$('.list').each(function(){
 $(this).find('span').eq(arrList[3]-1).text('Я третий');
  // -1, потому что отсчёт в массиве с "0", а ".eq" считает с "1"
});
```

```css
span {display: block; width: 100px; height: 20px; background: #333; margin: 0 0 2px; text-align: center; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```